# display/show STP file contents after uploading on web browser

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

how to show the content of Stp file on browser using spring mvc.
 i tried to use three.js and integrate it in my project but no chance 
help please?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hello can someone help me ??

Comment: Did you read the suggested links? What did you learn from them?

Comment: yes i did  i am new here so what should i do

Comment: First: Apply the newly learned techniques to your question by editing it.

Comment: @h.zammel Hi, I'm having the same problem. Did you figure this out? Could you share the step of the solution or the module you used?